# Use model helper to return list throw an exception

Tags: c#

I have a simple model helper like:

```
public class VarcharIdTableType
{
        public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

So I want to send it to my api using another model:

```
public class NewModel
{
    public IList<VarcharIdTableType> RangeValues { get; set; } = new List<VarcharIdTableType>();
}
```

So I create two lists as:

```
var alphabetRange = new List<VarcharIdTableType>();
var numericRange = new List<VarcharIdTableType>();
```

Then I want to add values to that list as:

```
char[] charAlphabetArray = Enumerable.Range(fromValue, toValue - fromValue + 1 ).Select(i => (char)i).ToArray();

for (int i = 0; i < charAlphabetArray.Length; i++)
{
    alphabetRange.Add(charAlphabetArray[i].ToString());
}
```

But it throws me an error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to
>   'Models.Helpers.VarcharIdTableType'

Can someone tell me what I'm missing in my code? Regards

Comment: The call to ToString makes it a string which is not a varchartanleid , it's a string. So you can't add it to your list that contains varchartanleid instances

Comment: `alphabetRange.Add()` expects an instance of `Models.Helpers.VarcharIdTableType` but you're passing in a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're code is actually trying to create a List of string instead of a list of VarcharIdTableType.

Try this:

```
alphabetRange.Add(new VarcharIdTableType { Id = charAlphabetArray[i].ToString() });
```

Or create a constructor for VarcharIdTableType to initialize the Id property that way.